# VSCode does not show HTML attributes in .vue files but shows in html files

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vetur

I have spent 3 hours figuring out what's going on but could not find it out. I am new to HTML and intellisense help me know many attributes of a tag on the go. However, with .vue files html attributes are not being shown up.

a) Attributes being shown up in **"index.html"**

[image]

b) No attributes hints in **"TodoItem.vue"**

[image]

I have already installed Vetur, HTML CSS Support and Vue VSCode Snippets extension from marketplace.

Comment: just tried input type="<at this place dropdown with types is appeared>". Try to input double quotes

Comment: @Anatoly I tried that also even before posting. I am still not getting the hints. https://imgur.com/a/Ep489dP

Comment: I have Vetur only with default settings.

Comment: I just typed '<input ty' it it suggests 'type'. I press Tab key and it adds type="" then I press Ctrl+Space and see all available options for 'type'

Comment: @Anatoly my bad! I was trying it with button tag instead of input tag. I dont know how I overlooked it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

First, install **Vetur** extension after that go to

> File > Preferences > Settings

In the list find and open Extensions find Vetur, scroll down and find Template Interpolation Service (must be checked).

[image]

[image]

Comment: This works, but it still feels like woefully short of the default HTML autocompletion. Not closing tags, styles not suggested, wish you could just enable the html stuff for this extension somehow.

Comment: Still this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

you need to install this official extension to get tailwind css hints.

**Tailwind CSS IntelliSense**

everything will come true